# Can we use laravel-permissions for multi tenant application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am creating one multi-tenant app in Laravel with Single Database and thinking to use laravel-permission package by spatie.

My Requirement is pretty straightforward, I want my tenants to create their own Roles, whereas permissions will be managed by Super Admin only.

My problem is when I was trying using, It worked for 1st client but 2nd time it gives error:

A role `'Admin' already exists for guard 'admin'`.

As I mentioned client can create roles, so they can crate duplicate roles.

Please recommend better approach or package or should I try writing custom code.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because the name is indexed in the role table, you cannot create a duplicate role name, I ask you not to change the package, but in case you have 2 ways to handle this

1- unindex the name collemn or disable unique feature, and add you tenant id to table so by do this you can manage and get right role for each tenant

2- add another table to manage your sub role (tenant role) and connect you sub role with master role by id

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, yes even I don't like to touch package. I already have added client_id column in roles table. Even I was thinking 1st option, I try both and update see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a hidden `prefix:` on the `roles` and `permissions` that would scope them to a particular tenant. So for example:

**Roles**

```
system:admin
tenant_a:admin
tenant_b:admin
```

**Permissions**

```
system:creates-roles
system:reads-roles
tenant_a:creates-roles
tenant_a:reads-roles
```

The `prefix` would not be assignable by a `Tenant`, the system would automatically assign that based on the `User`. However, if you're a `System` `Admin` (i.e. `Super Admin`) then you could create/view/assign a `prefix` in order to manage the `roles` and `permissions`.

This would require you to write some custom logic for handling the `prefix`, however, it is pretty flexible (you **could** nest unlimited identifiers - `a:b:c:d:e` etc.) and doesn't require you to go messing with any underlying packages (i.e. `laravel-permissions`).